# What is the correct way to initiate a class in a class?

Tags: c#, class

What is the correct way to initiate a class in a class? should I put StreamWriter in a method? or this is fine?

```
class Class1
{
   public static string config = "file.config";
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(config); 
   public void print (string log) 
   {
     writer.WriteLine(log);
   } 
   public void log_close() 
   { 
      writer.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please use `{}` tags to format the code. By now, you should have learnt it.

Comment: Your example won't compile - the initialiser for `writer` can't reference `config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closing logic is not thread-safe and does not follow recommendations.

You should use the Disposable pattern because FileStream implements IDisposable.

```
class Class1 : IDisposable
{ 
   public string config = "file.config";
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(config); 
   public void print (string log) 
   {
     writer.WriteLine(log);
   } 

   public void log_close() 
   { 
      Dispose();
   }

   public void Dispose() 
   { 
      if (writer != null)
         writer.Close();

      writer = null;
   }
}
```

And now your Class1 instances can be use with the `using` statement:

```
using (var c = new Class1())
{
    c.print("That's all");
}
```

No need to call Dispose() or close().

Comment: what's the purpose of the final `writer = null` line?

Comment: @John - to make multiple calls to Dispose() safe. Usually there is a `bool isDisposed` field, mine is a shortcut.

Comment: Should be `class Class1 : IDisposable`, not `class Class1 : IDisposable()`

Answer (score 1):

Consider following code:

```
class LogWriter : IDisposable
{
   public const string configFileName = "file.config";
   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(configFileName);

   public void Print(string log) 
   {
     writer.WriteLine(log);
   }

   public void CloseLog() 
   { 
      writer.Close();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      CloseLog();
   }
}
```

When you have some resources, that should be released (like files), good way is implementing `IDisposable` interface. Users of your class will know, that class should be disposed after usage.

Also naming - in C# we name methods PascalCase. And give more meaningful names to your classes and variables: LogWriter instead of Class1, configFileName instead of config.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you are doing.  Unless you have some need to re-initialize the `writer` to a new object later on, there's no reason to put it in a method.

However, the way this is written, it is allowing the `config` string to be changed.  At that point, it seems like you would want to move the instantiation of the `writer` into a method so that you can instantiate a new one upon first use and also any time the `config` string changes.  However, if `config` doesn't need to change after the class is constructed, you should ask for the file name in the constructor and instantiate the objects there:

```
class Logger : IDisposable
{
    StreamWriter writer;

    public void Logger(string configFileName)
    {
        writer = new StreamWriter(configFileName);
    }

    public void Print(string text) 
    {
        writer.WriteLine(text);
    } 

    public void Dispose()
    {
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

As others have pointed out, making your class implement `IDisposable` and using better naming conventions is also advisable.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your StringWriter in the local classes private scope. This is generally done when variables are shared between more than one method. However, you should manage your public variables, especially those that implement IDisposable, such as StringBuilder.

As you are accessing the StringBuilder in two methods, it's fine to declare it in that scope. However, you should close and dispose of the object manually when the object is destructed by the garbage collector.

You can use a C# class destructor, which is detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Disposing objects in the destructor isn't great.  The idea is to free the resources as soon as you can rather than leaving them open until the GC gets around to destructing your object.

Answer (score -1):

The initialization of fields that you initialize like that are moved to the top of the constructor at compile time.

```
class Class1
{
    String foo = "bar";
    String bar;

    public Class1()
    {
        bar = "baz";
    }
}
```

becomes

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit FieldInitialization.Class1
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .field private string bar

    .field private string foo

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldstr "bar"
        IL_0006: stfld string FieldInitialization.Class1::foo
        IL_000b: ldarg.0
        IL_000c: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0011: nop
        IL_0012: nop
        IL_0013: ldarg.0
        IL_0014: ldstr "baz"
        IL_0019: stfld string FieldInitialization.Class1::bar
        IL_001e: nop
        IL_001f: ret
    }
}
```

So it's really a matter of style where you choose to initialize them. However when an object you want to initialize depends on other, non-static fields, methods or properties, you'll have to initialize them in the constructor. Otherwise you'll get the compile error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

In the case of a IDispisable resource like the StreamWriter (or a Bitmap for example), you should keep in mind the issues pointed out by others.

Comment: How is an IL dump an answer to this question?

Comment: @HenkHolterman OP asks _"should I put StreamWriter in a method? or this is fine?"_, and I point out that it's a matter of style and does not affect the program in any way.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that might be the specific case here, but the question is wider: _"What is the correct way to initiate a class in a class?"_. There are different ways to do that.